# Background fetch in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, background

Does the background app refresh/background fetch work if the iOS has suspended or purged your app due to low memory? Will the iOS wake up the app for background fetch when more memory is available? Is there a way to ensure your app wont be purged by the OS?

Answer (score 0):

To simply answer your question, yes.

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) states, "At appropriate times, the system gives background execution time to the apps that support this background mode, launching the app directly into the background if needed."